# Updating Bugzilla installed via apt-get on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, bugzilla

I have installed and been using Bugzilla for a while on a current version 32-bit Ubuntu Server. I installed it via apt-get bugzilla3, but then I wrote a class to access it via XML-RPC and noticed a lot of functions were missing. I looked at the versions and the version I have installed is 3.2.5.1-2 and the current version from Mozilla is 3.6.2. Thus a few functions are missing in my installation. I don't seem to be able to upgrade to the current version using apt-get and I was wondering if anyone has any idea of how to go about doing this? The best way would be if there is a repo that has 3.6.2 that can be used via apt-get. Otherwise I'm a bit nervous that downloading the tar ball and installing that could screw up my setting and current installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/bugzilla3) for 3.6.2 in the latest ubuntu release. If all the dependencies are available for your ubuntu version you should be able to install that package on your server. If not, you can look at building a new binary package from the maverick source package.